# Sitecore 8.0 Visitor Rules availability

Tags: personalization

Do we have below 2 conditions available in Rule Set Editor for Personalization in Sitecore 8.0? If not, do we have any alternatives except custom rule creation?

1. Where the specific campaign was triggered during a past or current
   interaction and when the number of elapsed days compares to number
   and when the past number of interactions compares to number
2. Where the specific campaign was triggered during a past or current
       interaction and when the number of elapsed days compares to number
       and when the past number of interactions compares to number and the
       custom data compares to value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In short; No.

These exist in Sitecore 8.2.

[image]

In 8.0, these do not exist. As seen here.

[image]

You could attempt to move them backwards, but it will likely be fairly involved given the changes to xDB between 8.0 and 8.2.  Alternatively, as you say, you are stuck writing custom conditions for these.

Answer (score 1):

@Mark his answer is correct. As an additional to his answer on moving the rules backwards: This might not be so easy. OOTB you only have access to data stored in the xDB Shared Session, the shared session state data includes all data that is unique to a contact and that can be shared across simultaneous sessions, the Shared Session includes data as contact details, devices and engagement automation states triggered.

Campaign data is stored in the private session and only available during that current visit. That's why the rule "where the specific campaign was triggered during the **current** visit' is available.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/session_state/session_state